# How to bulk export Attachments from emails (which are emails) to another folder within Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to extract .msg attachments from emails in a range and save these into another outlook sub-folder. This works currently by dragging the attachment into a sub-folder of 'inbox' but is there a quicker way?

I have searched around a bit and found ways to extract them to a local folder but i need them to be contained within outlook.

I appreciate any help and suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here - first is accessing embedded message attachments without saving them first as MSG file. Second is importing the MSG files back - you can use Application.CreateItemFromTemplate, but the item will be unsent. You can use Namespace.OpenSharedItem, and then use MailItem.Move, but it is still a kludge.

There issn't much much you can do in OOM alone. Extended MAPI would work, but it is C++ or Delphi only. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am its author), you can use `EmbeddeedMsg` property exposed by the Redemption [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm) object. You can also use [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`CopyTo` and pass a folder as a parameter to copy an embedded message attachment to a folder:

```
Set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set redItem = Session.GetMessageFromId(OutlookMessage.EntryID)
set redFolder = Session.GetFolderFromId(OutlookFolder.EntryID)
for each attach in redItem.Attachments
  if attach.Type = olEmbeddeditem Then
    attach.EmbeddedMsg.CopyTo OutlookFolder
  End If
next
```